# prove - For symetric matrix with zero diagonal there exists $UU^t$ s.t $A+2I=UU^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen this in a book I am reading it seems that this is straight forward, but unfortunately my algebraic skills not good enough.

$A$ is symmetric with zeros on its diagonal, we need to prove that there exist matrix $U$ s.t
$$
A+2 I=U U^{T}
$$

Comment: Is $A$ of a specific size?

Comment: no, only symmetric with real values

Comment: You need to state the field.... is it $\mathbb C$? The statement is clearly false when working over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It would help to specify the book and chapter/section. If someone else has it, they can read it and see if the context adds any relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample for real matrices is $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Note that, if $A+2I=UU^t$ for some matrix $U$, then for any real vector $v$ we have $$v^t (A+2I)v=v^tUU^t v=(U^t v)^t (U^tv)=\|U^t v\|^2$$
which cannot be negative if $U$ (and therefore $U^t v$) is real. But if $v=(1,-1)^t$ then
$$v^\top (A+2I)v
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3\\3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=-2.
$$
Hence no real matrix $U$ exists. Matters are different if we allow complex-valued $U$. For instance, Mathematica's `FindInstance` command generates the example $U=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\ -i \sqrt{5/2} & -3/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: If $U$ is allowed to be complex, then I would suspect that the transpose should really be a Hermitian conjugate. But then the conjecture is definitely false. Each row of $U$ would have norm $\sqrt{2}$, so if any element of $A$ had a greater magnitude, then $A$ would be a counterexample. So there doesn’t seem to be any way to save this without imposing additional conditions on $A$.

Comment: @sasquires Agreed. One needs $A+2I$ to be PSD to forbid the kind of counterexample I give above. So if none of the eigenvalues of $A$ are smaller than $-2$, then it should be fine.